# Await returning undefined into the async function (var all_courses is undefined)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I am trying to return the courses that belong to a certain program. for that I use the async / await but it is not returning the courses of the program that happened as id in the asynchronous function:

**Program Controller**

```
function getProgram(req, res){
     var programId = req.params.id;

     Program.findById({'_id': programId}, (err, program)=>{

        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Petition failed'});

        if (!program) return res.status(404).send({message: 'There is not program to show'});

        getCoursesByProgram(programId).then((value) =>{
            return res.status(200).send({
                program,
                all_courses: value.all_courses
           });
        });
     });
 }

async function getCoursesByProgram(program_id){

     var all_courses = await Course.find({'program': program_id}).exec((err, courses)=>{
         if(err) return handleError(err);       
        return courses;
     });    
       return{
           all_courses: all_courses
     }
 }
```

**Models**

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CourseSchema = Schema({

   title: String,
   video: String,
   creator: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
   program: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Program'},
   description: String,
   created_at: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);


'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProgramSchema = Schema({

   title: String,
   creator: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
   image: String,
   description: String,
   created_at: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Program', ProgramSchema);
```

Please somebody can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a callback to `.exec`, it no longer returns a promise. Instead, you can do error / value handling using promises:

```
try {
  return { all_courses: await Course.find({'program': program_id}).exec() };
} catch (err) {
  return handleError(err);       
}
```

Note that `getCoursesByProgram` will always resolve unless `handleError` throws an error.

---

`getProgram` can also be an async function. You can consolidate the error handling too, although if you want more generalized error handling you will have to either catch the errors independently or parse the error messages somehow.

```
async function getProgram(req, res) {
  try {
    const programId = req.params.id;

    const program = await Program.findById({'_id': programId}).exec();
    if (!program) return res.status(404).send(...);

    const courses = await getCoursesByProgram(programId);
    return res.status(200).send({
      program,
      all_courses: value.all_courses,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'Petition failed' });
  }
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem by changing the .exec () to .then (), but thank you very much for your answer. I'll keep it in mind